# Finding the points on a curve, closest to a specific point

Tags: calculus

Find the point(s) on the curve $y^3=x^2$ closest to the point $P=(0,4).$
I understand that there is a way to solve this, using the distance formula, however this turns out to seem rather complicated. I am also aware that there is a calculus method to solving this question, however am unsure as to what that method is, exactly.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The square of the distance between the point $P$ and another point with coordinates $(x,y)$ is 
$$d^2=x^2+(y-4)^2.$$

Since the curve is defined as a set of points $(x,y)$ related to each other by the relation $y^3=x^2$, we have the square of the distance from $P$ to the curve equal to:
$$d^2=y^3+(y-4)^2$$
Thus, the task is to find the smallest $d$ possible, when $d$ is actually a function of $y$. For this, we employ the derivative of $d(y)$ to find extremums of the function:
$$d(y)=\sqrt{y^3+(y-4)^2}$$
$$d'(y)=\frac{3y^2+2(y-4)}{2\sqrt{y^3+(y-4)^2}}$$
Now, to find extremums, solve $d'(y)=0$, or in our case $3y^2+2(y-4)=0$. This quadratic equation has two solutions $y=-2$ and $y=\frac{4}{3}$. But the solution $y=-2$ is not acceptable, since $y^3=x^2$, and that would mean $-8=x^2$. Hence, we are left with only one solution and two pairs (do you know why?) of points:

$(\frac{8}{\sqrt{28}},\frac{4}{3})$ and $(-\frac{8}{\sqrt{28}},\frac{4}{3})$.

P.S. I did not check that obtained solution is actually a minimum. Can you validate that?

Edit: Dear reviewer, I want to edit the typo in "suare" to "square". Stupid StackExchange doesn't let me because it's less then 6 symbols!

Comment: Thank you! Using the second derivative test I got f''(x)= 6y+2 and then subbed in the value for y, resulting in an answer of 10, thus confirming that the solution is a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The distance is $ \sqrt{x^2+(y-4)^2}$

replace $x^2$ with $y^3$, the distance become $ \sqrt{y^3+(y-4)^2}$

Let $u(y) = y^3+(y-4)^2$ find the stationary point of u(y):

$u'(y) = 3y^2+2y-8 = 0 $ => $y = -2$ or $4/3$

substitute the roots into distance function and choose the minimal one.

References:
[correlation between stationary points and extrema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point)

[Basic identities of derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules)